# Python: how to use character value and code point

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I've read a bunch about ord and chr, but so far I am stuck.
What I need is to be able to do the following:

I have a byte array of code points thus in range 0-255
For each of them I want the associated utf-8 character
I then need to concatenate those characters and use the resulting string as an array of bytes, not the array of their code points!

I've tried to see the string as a bytearray encoded in iso-8859-1 but so far, no luck.
Any help appreciated!

Current code:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
msg = ''
sys.setdefaultencoding('iso-8859-1')
for m in bytearray(input, 'iso-8859-1', ''):
    msg += unichr(m)
msg = bytearray(msg, 'iso-8859-1')
```

Comment: What's wrong with decoding as "iso-8859-1" and encoding as "utf-8"?

Comment: Well actually my 'input' is a bytearray. And I'd like a bytearray out as well. Could you show me some sample code? I cannot exactly figure out what you mean, sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those who wonder, I found the solution myself after more digging, but I would take a more python oriented way of doing things if you know of one!

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('iso-8859-1')
mm = bytearray(input)
msg = bytearray()
for m in mm:
    val = bytearray(unichr(m), 'utf-8')
    for v in val:
        msg.append(v)
# revert if required
# sys.setdefaultencoding('ascii')
```

Comment: As I've written - i  is uselees and prone to get you strange errors trying to change the defaut encoding. Also, there is no need to convertthigns to bytearray and run an explict  `for` in order to encode/decode characters.

Answer (score 0):

No need to fiddle with "defautlencoding" - just leave it as it is - you have your data, and the encodings you want.The Python interpreter has its default values - that nterface with the OS terminal, and so on.

So, assuming you have a bytearray named `input` with encodning in iso-8859-1 (latin1), for which you want the corresponding utf-8 encoded text, jsut do:

```
result = bytearray(bytes(input).decode("iso-8859-1").encode("utf-8"))
```

The output of the "encode"  method is itself a "bytes" object - and bytes and bytearray objects can be transparently built one from the other.

(yes, that line is all you need - no need to import `sys`, use a `for` loop, or additional encoding calls).

Comment: My goal is actually not to get the bytes encoded as utf-8, but to consider the bytes in input as codes that would code utf-8 values.

Actually, in PHP, could be:

                   `public static function isoUTF($str) {
   $ret = '';
   $l = strlen($str);
   for($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
    $code = mb_convert_encoding('&#' . ord($str[$i]) . ';', 'utf-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
    for($j = 0; $j < strlen($code); $j++) {
     $ret .= $code[$j];
    }
   }
   return $ret;
  }`

Comment: If you have o consider the byts as utf-8, jst decode them passing "utf-8" as the codec name. 

But before resuming coding, maybe you'd be better reading this - please do that for yourself: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html